# How can I run 32-bit Eclipse on 64-bit ubuntu?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, x86, virtual-machine

I have a customized version of Eclipse which is for 32-bit only. And I've got to run it on 64-bit ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It is not possible to download a standard 64-bit Eclipse or to run a 32-bit VM. Are there any simple and reliable ways of doing this?
Chroot or ia32-libs seem to be not the best option due to reliability / practicality reasons.

Comment: Why do you think a 32-bit version of Eclipse can't run on a 64-bit OS? Also, why do you think a 32-bit build would be less reliable or less practical than the 64-bit build of the very same code base?

Comment: @H2CO3 There are other reasons than reliability.  I for one am forced to use a 32 bit native windows .dll for one application and that requires a 32 bit java.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest would be the installation of 32bit libs.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

then reboot

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit

There are 4 suggestions on that page:

```
Installation of 32-bit compatibility libraries (ia32-libs or Multiarch support)

A 32-bit chroot

Full virtualization through KVM or VirtualBox

Another option in a pinch is getlibs getlibs
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an old post (2007) which might help you:
http://rachaelandtom.info/node/1485